# Tcp Client connection issue with T-mobile and s9

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, samsung-mobile

I have an app that has been working fine for a couple of years now. Last week I found an issue that ONLY happen (so far) in T Mobile with an S9 phone. The call the TcpClient.Connect is stuck and timeout.
Again this just happen in an S9 from T Mobile with the WIFI off, As soon as I connect the WIFI the issue does not happen.

This is my code:

```
var tcpc = new TcpClient();
tcpc.Connect( remoteAddress, remotePort);
```

I have tested both versions of Connect with the address (above) and using the IP:

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match( remoteAddress , @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+").Success)
   tcpc.Connect(IPAddress.Parse( remoteAddress ), remotePort);
```

In both cases it fails.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Naura

Comment: Are you using TCPv6? Does your server have a publicly addressable IP address assigned?

Comment: The server is in Azure , I do not believe it has a IPv6

Comment: Did you try pinging the address from command line?

Comment: Yes. Again this just happen in an S9 from T Mobile with the WIFI off. If you turn the WIFI on everything works fine

Comment: Were you able to solve this?